ALM Quality Center REST Api endpoints
im currently trying to get recieve the "Details", "Test Script" and " Parameters" of a "BUSINESS-PROCESS".
Im coding this in java.
Currently my biggest issue is that i dont know the endpoints.
Is there somewhere a list of the endpoints cause i wasnt able to find it.
Im trying to get the tests via the "Test ID" that can be found in "Details".
Im ablet to get the "Details" with this endpoint:
new URL(almServer + "/qcbin/rest/domains/" + domain + "/projects/" + project + "/tests/" + testId).
From manual tests im also able to get the design steps with this approach :
new URL(almServer + "/qcbin/rest/domains/" + domain + "/projects/" + project
+ "/design-steps/?query={parent-id[" + testId + "]}")
But i cant get the "Test Script" steps or the "Parameters"
Is the idea of the approach already false? Would you guys do this task in a different way ?
I looked up endpoints but couldnt find them.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
